# Node.js MySQL connection not being released properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I think my connections aren't being released properly. Sometimes I get an error stating that my pool has reached its limit. Also, sometimes accessing the db randomly takes 15+ seconds. Whenever I check how many connections are in use using `pool._allConnections.length`, it never returns anything above 60. Here is my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = require('./config.json');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 999,
  host: config.host,
  user: config.user,
  password: config.password,
  database: config.database
});

const db = (() => {

  _query = (query, params, callback) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {

      if (err) {
        callback(null, err);
      } else {
        connection.query(query, params, (err, rows) => {
          connection.release();
          if (!err) {
            callback(rows);
          } else {
            callback(null, err);
          }
        });
      }

    });
  };

  return {
    query: _query
  };
})();

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 1):

i've faced same issue and https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1518 help me. Notice line

> Yeah, that was the issue. I was calling mysql.createPool on each
>   query.

Actually you are importing db from query.js (let say your post code) to fire a query. every time you fire a query it create a new pool.to solve this issue you can put **createPool**  code block to app.js and can share it global or can use in query.js via any other code style. 
Referring official doc https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections find line

> Since the pool.query method is a short-hand for the pool.getConnection
>   -> connection.query -> connection.release() flow, calling pool.end() before all the queries added via pool.query have completed,

later i used this to stop headache of release connection